# HTML5 Canvas - draw

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Circle example are listed bebelow

Here is my JavaScript code.

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your sample is missing the code for `randomColor`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `randomColor` is correct all you will need is to:

- Remove `context.clearRect` from the canvas.onclick
- Move `context.beginPath` to the canvas.onclick

Here is a working sample

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function randomColor() {
  colorArray = ["red", "blue", "green", "lime", "orange", "cyan"]
  return colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
}


// click event handler
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  y = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;

  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = randomColor();
  context.arc(x, y, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: @ktbffh Open a new question with what you have and what are you trying to make disappear and I will help you, as much as I can. ... and please create a working code snippet